# How can I hook and edit on the fly an image uploaded in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, image, upload, hook

I'm new in wordpress plugin development and I'm trying to hook my function to one of wordpress's upload / attachements functions. 
My target is to:
- hook to wordpress function (I've tried: wp_handle_upload, wp_handle_upload_prefilter)
- use image/media resource in my function (apply filter on image)
- return modified resource to further processing by wordpress core.

Is there a way to achieve that?

The code I'm using is similar to:

```
add_filter('wp_handle_upload', 'handle_upload');

function handle_upload($resource){

   $tools->tool_blurImage($resource);

return $resource;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The `$resource` passed to the function is an array of 3 elements:

- `file` is the absolute path to the image file;
- `url` is the url to the image;
- `type` is the mime type of the file (i.e. `image/jpeg`).

So if your `$tools->tool_blurImage` function accept the file path as parameter you should check if the file is an image and then pass the file path:

```
function handle_upload($resource) {

    if( 'image' == substr( $resource['type'], 0, 5 ) )
        $tools->tool_blurImage($resource['file']);

    return $resource;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The only way I can apply the filter on the image is when the image is uploaded. I was trying to apply when the image was not reaching the "uploads" folder.